# How to pass SIGINT to child process with Python subprocess.Popen() using shell = true

Tags: python, gdb, subprocess, popen, sigint

I am currently trying to write (Python 2.7.3) kind of a wrapper for GDB, which will allow me to dynamically switch from scripted input to interactive communication with GDB.

So far I use

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(["gdb vuln"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE,  shell = True)
```

to start gdb within my script. (`vuln` is the binary I want to examine)

Since a key feature of gdb is to pause the execution of the attached process and allow the user to inspect registers and memory on receiving SIGINT (STRG+C) I do need some way to pass a SIGINT signal to it.

Neither

```
self.process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

nor

```
os.kill(self.process.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

or

```
os.killpg(self.process.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

work for me.

When I use one of these functions there is no response. I suppose this problem arises from the use of `shell=True`. However, at this point I am really out of ideas.
Even my old friend Google couldn't really help me out this time, so maybe you can help me. Thank's in advance.

Cheers, Mike

Comment: A target process created by gdb will be in a new pgrp, so sending SIGINT to gdb or to gdb's pgrp won't work. You could use python's pty package and send `^C` to it, I guess, but it sounds like you may want to use gdb's async mode, in which the target runs while gdb still accepts commands, and the gdb `interrupt` command will pause the target. If you describe your use case a bit more, we can offer suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however running in async mode is not an option for me.

Basically what I finally want to achieve is, to have a loop which reads lines from console and writes it to the stdin of self.process until a certain string (e.g. "quit") is read. 
While in this loop the program should catch STR+C (=SIGINT) if pressed by the user and pass it to gdb, in order to achieve the same behaviour as if gdb was run regularly.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what worked for me:

```
import signal
import subprocess

try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(...)
    p.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    p.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked deeper into the problem and found some interesting things. Maybe these findings will help someone in the future.

When calling `gdb vuln` using suprocess.Popen() it does in fact create three processes, where the pid returned is the one of `sh` (5180).

```
ps -a
 5180 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
 5181 pts/0    00:00:00 gdb
 5183 pts/0    00:00:00 vuln
```

Consequently sending a SIGINT to the process will in fact send SIGINT to `sh`.

Besides, I continued looking for an answer and stumbled upon this post
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9039

To keep it short, what is mentioned there is the following:

When pressing STRG+C while using gdb regularly SIGINT is in fact sent to the examined program (in this case `vuln`), then ptrace will intercept it and pass it to gdb. 
What this means is, that if I use `self.process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` it will in fact never reach gdb this way.

### Temporary Workaround:

I managed to work around this problem by simply calling `subprocess.popen()` as follows:

`subprocess.Popen("killall -s INT " + self.binary, shell = True)`

This is nothing more than a first workaround. When multiple applications with the same name are running might do some serious damage. Besides, it somehow fails, if `shell=True` is not set. 
If someone has a better fix (e.g. how to get the pid of the process startet by gdb), please let me know.

Cheers, Mike

### EDIT:

Thanks to Mark for pointing out to look at the ppid of the process. 
I managed to narrow down the process's to which SIGINT is sent using the following approach:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-Aefj'])
for line in out.splitlines():
    if self.binary in line:
        l = line.split(" ")
        while "" in l:
            l.remove("")
        # Get sid and pgid of child process (/bin/sh)
        sid = os.getsid(self.process.pid)
        pgid  = os.getpgid(self.process.pid)
        #only true for target process
        if l[4] == str(sid) and l[3] != str(pgid):
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: You quoted from bugzilla.kernel.org. Are you running Linux? You can look at the `status` files under `/proc` to find the target process, examining the `Name` and `Ppid` entries to find a process with the desired app name and grandparent == self.process.pid.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like the following in the past and if I recollect it seemed to work for me :

```
def detach_procesGroup():
    os.setpgrp()

subprocess.Popen(command,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                 preexec_fn=detach_processGroup)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However it didn't work for me :(

Comment: the effect is the opposite: it prevents propagating `Ctrl+C` from console to the child process. And it has no effect on the grandchild process started by `gdb`  (`gdb` may create yet another process group).

Answer (score 0):

A modification of @sirex answer, which worked better for me:

```py
import signal
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(...)
while True:
    try:
        p.wait()
        exit(0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

The original code would abort after the 2nd `ctrl-C`.