# Break pyinotify notifier loop

Tags: python, pyinotify

I'm using `pyinotify.notifier` to keep track of changes in a text file.

When I get an specific change in it, I want to break the notifier loop. By using `notifier.stop()` seems to not work.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
class ModHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, evt):
        #... Do Stuff
        if "Expected change":
               #break notifier loop

if __name__ == "__main__":

    handler = ModHandler()
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
    wdd = wm.add_watch('example.file', pyinotify.IN_MODIFY)
    notifier.loop()
    #when finished the loop, do more stuff
```

How can break the thread loop and return to the main program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial) states that:

> `notifier.loop()`
>   The call to this method is blocking until we type `c-c` (sigint)

So that's what you need to do. **Send a sigint signal**. 
Some ways of doing that:

- [How to send a SIGINT to Python from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974189/how-to-send-a-sigint-to-python-from-a-bash-script)
- [How to pass SIGINT to child process with Python subprocess.Popen() using shell = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925198/how-to-pass-sigint-to-child-process-with-python-subprocess-popen-using-shell)
- [Send SIGINT in python to os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356837/send-sigint-in-python-to-os-system)
- [Send SIGINT to Python subprocess using os.kill as if pressing Ctrl+C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578799/send-sigint-to-python-subprocess-using-os-kill-as-if-pressing-ctrlc)

Comment: It worked. I've add `os.kill(os.getpid(),signal.SIGINT)` and it finished the loop. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.9.0 you can stop notifier loop by passing a callback function. When evaluated to True, breaks the loop and stops the notifier.

https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Recent-Developments#changes-introduced-with-pyinotify-090